# How to use an ngrx selector that has a parameter that depends on another selector

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to use an ngrx selector that takes a property of jobId to return some data as an observable.

I'm first loading all of the jobs and tasks from a database but they don't come back in time for the selectors and I get an error because this.task is undefined, which I believe is keeping the observable from running again.

Is there a way to wait for the data to return before the selectors try to fetch the data from the store?

```js
this.store.dispatch(fromTasks.loadAllTasks());
this.store.dispatch(fromJobs.loadAllJobs());

taskSubscription$ = this.store.pipe(
 select(fromTask.getSelectedTask),
 tap(task => this.task = task)).subscribe()

jobSubscription$ = this.store.pipe(
 select(fromJob.getJobById, {jobId: this.task.jobId}),
 tap(job => this.job = job)).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach you can consider :

1) Selector `getSelectedTask` return `null` if no selected task

```
export const getSelectedTask = createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  getSelectedTaskId,
  (entities: Dictionary<Task>, selectedId: number) => {
    return selectedId ? entities[selectedId] : null;
  }
)
```

2) Use `async` pipe and `*ngIf` inside template

Component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  selectedTask$ = this.store.pipe(select(getSelectedTask));
...
}
```

Template.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedTask$ | async as selectedTask else noSelection">

  <my-task [task]="selectedTask"></my-task>
  // or 
  <span>{{ selectedTask.description }}</span>

</ng-container>

<ng-template #noSelection>
  Please select a task !
</ng-template>
```

With this approach, you will use the powerful of observables with angular template syntax. 
If user unselect current task, `getSelectedTask` selector will return `null` and template will be automatically updated.

Nevertheless, you can continue to use `subscription`, but in this case, prefer to set the value inside `subscribe` method and be sure to unsubscribe.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;
  selectedTask$ = this.store.pipe(select(getSelectedTask));
  selectedTask: Task;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.selectedTask$.subscribe(task 
      => this.selectedTask = task);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  If the selector returns null, won't that still cause an issue when it tries to run through the tap operations?

Comment: In which tap operations? You should avoid putting logic inside `tap` operator or inside `subscribe`. Prefer to create a new `selector`, for example `getSelectedJobs` which will return all jobs for the current task selected. In this case, you will be able to test `getSelectedId` or `getSelectedTask` and then return `null` also for `getSelectedJobs`. So your `*ngIf` will work perfectly in this case also. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use RxJS filter.

`taskSubscription$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(fromTask.getSelectedTask),
    filter(task => !!task),
    tap(task => this.task = task)).subscribe()`

Comment: This is working, but the drawback is `this.task` won't be assigned to `null` if there is later no more selected task, in this case, component will not be notified.

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to work, but I'm not really sure why.  Could you explain what the !!task is doing?

Comment: !!task means 'not not task'. It's just equivalent to `task !==undefined && task !== null`. In this case, as Thierry Falvo wrote, this.task won't be assigned to `null`. If 'null' is needed, you can write explicitly `task !=='undefined'` or use his solution. I hope you succeed!